# Exit Code on Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I keep getting Exit Code == 13 and Exit Code == 1 (changes on its mood).

I have tried editing the ini file and adding -vm and then the directory path to the java file I need before the -vmargs, no, none of it works.

Comment: Your ini file is probably wrong but how can anyone help you if they can't see it?

Comment: Exit code 13 normally means you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. Both Eclipse and Java must be 64 bit or both 32 bit. Recent releases of Eclipse are 64 bit only.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is probably java version (32 or 64 bit). Try to install jdk8

Windows x86 202.73 MB   jdk-8u221-windows-i586.exe

Windows x64 215.35 MB   jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe